# Svelte dev mode takes 20 seconds to refresh/compile/HMR when including bootstrap as inline style

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

In dev mode it takes 20 seconds to refresh/reload when including bootstrap in an inline style block.

@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

It's probably caused by Unused CSS selector check, which returns lot of erros because most of the bootstrap classes aren't used.

This only happens when including bootstrap in an inline style block.

I'm creating a web component that shouldn't leak any styles to host websites.
Unfortunately the only way to inject styles into the web-component is by using an inline style tag.

What am I doing wrong here? Ideally it should compile in less than a second every time I make a change to a source file.

Or is there another way to add bootstrap to web components?

[image]

Comment: @possum I added an explicit question

Comment: Importing the CSS from JS is not the same as inlining.  AFAIK, all this does is tell Vite to emit the CSS resource file.